# Using Python to generate URLs with names from txt

Tags: python, url, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm hoping someone can help me generate a list of unique URLs based on information in a text file.

Example: I have the base URL, www.website.com/users/, and a txt file with usernames, 'frank', 'rachel', 'james', etc. And I want to create URLs with this information, and save it to a txt file, like this:

```
www.website.com/users/frank
www.website.com/users/rachel
www.website.com/users/james
etc.
```

I have done something similar with numbers, e.g.

```
www.website.com/1
www.website.com/2
etc.
```

The code I wrote for the number solution is pasted below in case it's helpful as a starting point.

```
import time

htmlTxt=""
pageNum=0
x="http://forum.com/eforum/forumdisplay.php?fid=13&page="
y=x+str(pageNum)

file = open("URLs.txt", "wb")
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.001)  # do something here
        file.write(x +str(pageNum)+"\n")
    pageNum+=1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '\nPausing...  (Hit ENTER to continue, type quit to exit.)'
        try:
            response = raw_input()
            if response == 'quit':
                break
            print 'Resuming...'
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'Resuming...'
            continue
file.close()
```

(the reason I used 'time' in the example above is because I don't know how to make it stop at a certain number, so I just let it ran for a few seconds and deleted the URLs that went beyond the 'max' number.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you simplify your question? Is `www.website.com` the same site every time in the expected output? Where does it come from? What does the list of names look like? One per line in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file that contains names for reading, another one that will contain the output - for writing. Read the input file line by line and write to the output appending the name:

```
URL = "www.website.com/users/"

with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            output_file.write(URL + line)
```

For the `input.txt` that contains:

```
frank
rachel
james
```

it produces the following `output.txt`:

```
www.website.com/users/frank
www.website.com/users/rachel
www.website.com/users/james
```

Answer (score 1):

- Open the file with the usernames to read and output file to write.
- Read a line from the username file, construct the url and write it to output file.

  ```
  with open('usernames', 'r') as input_file, open('output', 'a') as output_file:
      for line in input_file:
          url = "http://website.com/{}".format(line.strip())
          output_file.write(url)
  input_file.close()
  output_file.close()
  ```

Comment: is `.format` better (more pythonic?) than just concatenating with `+`?

Comment: @Jasper The documentation says it is a newer way of formatting strings. I just prefer it for readability reasons.

Comment: OK, agreed in general, but I think I'd use `+` instead of `{}` if it's at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

On "how to make it stop at a certain number":
You can use a `for` loop, which is usually used to iterate over a list:

```
for i in range(maxnumber):
    # this body is executed maxnumber times and i is 0, 1, ..., maxnumber - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```
URL = "www.website.com/users/"

with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            output_file.write(URL + line)
```

Can you pls update the code for the following. Becouse this code output will go to separate lines.

```
URL = "www.website.com/users/"
URI_PART = "/set/passwd"

with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            new_url = URL + line + URI_PATH
            print(new_url)
```

Then the output URLs will split to 2 lines.
Do you have an idea for this?